# Continuous and non-decreasing but how?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I am reading a paper and the author shows the continuity and monotonicity of a function. It seems so simple to see but I am sorry that I couldnt see the reason. I will be very happy if you can point out the reason. The question is as follows:

**Question:** For given density functions $p_1(x)$ and $p_0(x)$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) the following equation is to be satisfied: $$(1-\epsilon_1)\{P_1[p_1/p_0>c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]\}=1.$$ Where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<\epsilon_1<1$. To claim that there exists a unique solution to this problem he needs to show that the function

$$f(c)=P_1[p_1/p_0>c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]$$

is continuous and monotone. The function $f(c)$ can be written as

$$f(c)=1-P_1[p_1/p_0\leq c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]$$ $$=1+\int_{[p_1/p_0\leq c]}(c-p_1/p_0)p_0 \mbox{d} \mu$$

From here he writes

$$f(c+\Delta)-f(c)=\int_{[c<p_1/p_0\leq c+\Delta]}(c+\Delta-p_1/p_0)p_0 \mbox{d}\mu+\Delta\int_{[p_1/p_0\leq c]}p_0\mbox{d}\mu$$

Where $\mu$ is some measure e.g., $\mu=P_0+P_1$. From here he claims that $$0 \leq f(c+\Delta)-f(c)\leq \Delta$$
For any positive $\Delta$, therefore continuity and monotonicity follow.

I cannot see why this should be true. I followed all the steps and I saw that everything is fine until the last step. Why it should be between $0$ and $\Delta$? I am stuck at this point((

**EDIT:** Although the paper doesnt mention, from another paper and from my own reading I also know that $p_1/p_0$ is also monotone increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the right-hand side of the equation for $f(c+\Delta)-f(c)$ as $A+B$.  Then
$$B=\Delta P_0(p_1/p_0\le c).\qquad(1)$$
In the first term, since the integral is over the region where $c<p_1/p_0\le c+\Delta$, the integrand satisfies the inequality
$$
\Delta p_0 \ge (c+\Delta-p_1/p_0)p_0\ge 0.
$$
Therefore, $$0\le A\le\Delta P_0(c<p_1/p_0\le c+\Delta).\qquad (2)$$
Then, adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$
\Delta P_0(p_1/p_0\le c)\le f(c+\Delta)-f(c)\le \Delta P_0(p_1/p_0\le c+\Delta).
$$
Since $P_0(\cdots)$ is between $0$ and $1$, it follows immediately that
$$0 \leq f(c+\Delta)-f(c)\leq \Delta.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear answer. I wonder one simple detail. So the choice of the measure is not very important. I guess $\mu=P_0+P_1$ can be chosen due to its some nice property? When I am defning such a measure how should I think about it? i am not able to imagine it in my mind; like how the process of integration is established when $\mu=P_0$ or $\mu=P_1$ or $\mu=P_0+P_1$. If you could comment on this, I will be very happy.